# sqlalchemy force close database connection

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I use the code to record long time queries in flask-sqlalchemy:

```
@home.after_app_request
def after_request(response):
    for query in get_debug_queries():
        if query.duration >= current_app.config.get('SLOW_DB_QUERY_TIME'):
            current_app.logger.warning(f'Slow query: {query.statement}\nParameters:{query.parameters}\n'
                                       f'Duration:{query.duration}\nContext:{query.context}\n')
    return response
```

The long time queries make my flask app look like stuck and I can't do anything in the site.

I use `show processlist` in mysql, the result shows that the long time query is sending data for a long time.

So I want to know how to force close these queries.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936226/python-flask-sqlalchemy-query-time-out-error

Comment: I add SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT to 10s, SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW to 100, but it seems not worked. The long time query costs longer time than SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT, but it still sending data and do not be killed.